# Pegar usuário logado do windows para autenticar automaticamente em um site publicado no IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

estou criando uma aplicação web com ASP.NET MVC 5, onde que quando um usuário da rede acessar o endereço da minha aplicação  pelo browser o sistemas já pegasse automaticamente qual usuário está tentando logar na aplicação. Atualmente tenho que digitar dominio\usuário e senha.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E no meu web.config estou utilizando , mas n gostaria que o sistema pedisse usuário e senha, somente se o usuario não estivesse no dominio. Lembrando que essa aplicação já esta publicada no servidor IIS 7.5 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor????

Comment: Se não me engano, no firefox não funciona direito. Tem que fazer alguma configuração.

Comment: Onde trabalho os usuários trabalham com os IE,Chrome e Firefox, gostaria de uma forma de autenticação automática independente de navegador ou  pelo menos funcionando, hehe.

Comment: Então, como eu disse: isso não funciona nativamente no Firefox, possivelmente vai ser necessário instalar um *add-on* **em todos** os Firefox.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vlw mano!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente, ou felizmente, não existe uma forma de padronizar. Isso vai de navegador para navegador.

No Internet Explorer e no Google Chrome ele consegue realizar essa autenticação automaticamente. Caso queira modificar as configurações, [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7800938/4843158) mostra como fazer isso.

Já no Firefox, você precisar utilizar algum *add-on* ([como dito pelo @jbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167333/pegar-usu%C3%A1rio-logado-do-windows-para-autenticar-automaticamente-em-um-site-publi#comment344435_167333)), tal como o [Integrated Authentication](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/integrated-auth-for-firefox/) ou alterar a [configuração padrão do firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/733309/4843158) (esta dependendo da versão do firefox).

Comment: Obrigado amigo, me ajudou bastante!! vlww